# Find all polynomials $P(x)$ such that $ x P(x-n)=(x-1) P(x) $

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

**Question** -

Find all polynomials $P(x)$ with real coefficients such that
$$
x P(x-n)=(x-1) P(x)
$$
for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

**My attempt** -

First by putting $x=0$, I get $p(0)=0$ ..
then the hint says that for $n>1$ show that $p(x)=0$ has infinitely many zeros...

I first let that another root $R$ is not equal to $0$..then by putting  $R$ in equation I get that $R-n$ is also root ...but I am unable to prove that there are infinitely roots...

Any hints ???

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case $n>1$**

As you noticed $P(0)=0$. Using this fact and evaluate the equality in $x=n$ you have:
\begin{gather}
nP(n-n) = (n-1)P(n)\\
0 = P(n)
\end{gather}

This procedure suggests (in some sense) the following statement:

> If $k\in \mathbb N$ and $kn$ is a root of $P(x)$, then $(k+1)n$ is a root of $P$.

Infact, evaluating the eqaulity in $(k+1)n$ knowing that $P(kn)=0$ we have:
\begin{gather}
(k+1)n P((k+1)n-n)) = ((k+1)n-1)P((k+1)n)\\
0 = P((k+1)n)
\end{gather}

Thanks to this fact, you have that the set $\{0,n,2n,3n, 4n,...\} = \{kn\}_{k\in \mathbb N}$ is a set of roots of $P$. Since it is infinity, $P(x)=0$.

---

**Case $n=1$**

Again we have $P(0)=0$ so $P(x)=xQ(x)$ for a certain polynomial $Q(x)$. Sobstituting this equality in the equality of the text we have:
\begin{gather}
x(x-1)Q(x-1)=x(x-1)Q(x)\\
Q(x-1)=Q(x)
\end{gather}
And this implies that $Q(x)=c$ with $c\in \mathbb R$. Then the polynomial $P(x)$ is necessarly of the form $P(x)=cx$ for some $c\in \mathbb R$ and every polynomial of this form works.

Edit: In the case $1$ we have to take linear increment and not exponential.

Comment: In fact you can see that also $P(3n)=0$ since $3nP(3n-n)=(3n-1)P(3n)$ and $P(2n)=0$. You can prove that all multiples of $n$ are solutions.

Comment: @user289143 You are right, but it's sufficient the set $\{2^i n\}$ that is an infinite set and then you obtain for all $k$. I mean, to prove your statement, I need to do some more induction's proof that are not necessary

Comment: one doubt , in above you write p(X)=0 because it has infinitely many roots....it can also be constant..i.e p(x)=c ...???

Comment: @User88463 
The argument is the following: $P(x)$ assumes the same value (that is $0$ in our case) for an infinite set of number, so $P(x)$ is a costant $c$. So you have the equality $P(x)=c$, but now you know (for example) that $P(0)=0$ so the constant has to be $c=0$.

Comment: ohh yes..thanks

Answer (score 1):

For $n>1$,

Given : $$
x P(x-n)=(x-1) P(x)
$$

Firstly put $x=1$ in above equation to get $P(1-n)=0$.

Then put $x=1-n$ again in that equation to conclude $P(1-2n)=0$ .Now put $x=1-2n$ and so on.

Can you continue this process indefinitely unless P is the zero polynomial?

For $n=1$, we have :

$xP(x-1)=(x-1)P(x)$

This implies $P(0)=0$. Now let $P(x)=xf(x)$, then we get :

$x(x-1)f(x-1)=(x-1)xf(x)$

This implies $f(x)=f(x-1)$ for all $x$ which is only possible when $f(x)$ is constant. Therefore $P(x)=cx$ for some constant $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it for $n=2$. Suppose that $xP(x-2) = (x-1)P(x)$ for all $x$ real. By substitution of $x=0$, $0 = -P(0)$ therefore $P(0) = 0$.

Next, note that $2P(2-2) = (2-1)P(2)$, the LHS is $0$, so the RHS is $0$ i.e. $P(2) = 0$.

Next, $4P(4-2) = (4-1)P(4)$, the LHS is $0$, therefore so is the RHS i.e. $P(4) = 0$.

By induction, $P(2n) = 0$ for all $n$. This is impossible if $P$ is a polynomial unless $P \equiv 0$.

Can you do something similar for other $n$?

---

Suppose $n = 1$. Then, we want a polynomial such that $xP(x-1) = (x-1)P(x)$.

Note that $x-1$ is relatively prime to $x$ as a polynomial, therefore $x$ must be a divisor of $P(x)$. Let $Q(x) = \frac{P(x)}{x}$ (as a polynomial, so at $0$ it will be well defined), then from $\frac{P(x)}{x} = \frac{P(x-1)}{x-1}$ we get that $Q$ has infinitely many values all equal to each other. Hence, $Q$ is a constant polynomial.

Thus , $P(x) = Cx$ for some constant $C$. Clearly, any such real constant works.